# maintenance of application log files sql

Tags: sql

I want to create a log table to keep track of users and their actions on website. For ex, when a user log in page a record will be created into log table. when user creates information, a record will be created into log table.  similarly for every action, a record will be created into log table.  In this way, the log table data will grow very faster.  What is the better way to maintain such bigger tables apart from creating trigger and scheduling scripts to clean data frequently?

Comment: you definitely do not want a trigger on the table if it is going to grow/change a lot!  For a high growth scenario that would mean every insert would do that operation and the trigger which will lead to blocking, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience typically excessive logging doesnt really gain you much. A lot of people lose the usefulness of logging with the sheer volume of it...just a little warning before hand.

As for maintaining a table that size i recommend potentially partitioning the table and writing a specific set of stored procedures that effectively use a few indexes that you place on the table. Any ad-hoc work on the table should be done minimally and if it is done make sure the ad-hoc hits up against any index you setup on the table. Also with (nolock) will be your friend for SELECT statements if a large amount of inserts going on.

This is the basic general idea I do for the transaction tables I handle and they typically get around 1-2 million rows a day.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  Yes I was thinking to partition table and use indexes.  And export table data to a file and clear the data regularly.